# What does "a.s." stand for?

Tags: abbreviation

I was reading an article and I saw the following sentence:

> For a given martingale, if it has an upper or a lower bound, then the
>   martingale must converge (a.s.). Since the likelihood is always
>   nonnegative, 0 is a lower bound.

What does "a.s." stand for? Is it a common usage?
My guess is "asymptotically" but I'd like to verify.

Comment: It stands for almost surely

Comment: @user33484 Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: Yes it is common usage.

Comment: @user33484 yeah, you basically lost 200-300 rep because it was a comment `:P`. Opportunity cost of 0.

Comment: a.s. stands for almost surely a.s.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It stands for "almost surely," i.e. the probability of this occurring is 1.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Answer (score 23):

As noted by @Matt, a.s. stands for "almost surely", or with probability 1.

Why the "almost" in "almost surely"? Because just because something  happens "almost surely" does not mean it must happen. For example, suppose $X \sim$ Uniform(0,1). What's $P(X = 0.5)$? Well, since $X$ is a continuous random variable, $P(X = $ any finite set of values) = 0. Therefore, $X$ is almost surely not equal to 0.5. But that's not to say $X$ cannot be equal to 0.5!

Comment: *"Just because something does not happen almost surely does not mean it cannot happen"*... well obviously. A fair coin doesn't come up heads almost surely but it can still come up heads. I think you meant to say something else.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Ah, there's some English ambiguity here. A less ambiguous statement: Just because $A$ happens a.s. does not mean it's impossible for $A$ not to happen. So in my example, $A$ is $X \ne 0.5$.

Comment: Yup... might want to modify your answer accordingly...

Comment: @Mehrdad Yeah, the intended parsing was "Just because (something does not happen) almost surely"; "Just because, almost surely, something does not happen" would have been clearer.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, a. s. stands for almost shurely, but in this case they are talking about almost shurely convergence. From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence),

> To say that the sequence $X_n$ converges **almost surely** or **almost everywhere** or **with probability 1** or **strongly** towards $X$ means that
>   $$Pr(\lim_{n\to\infty}{X_n}=X)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

As already noted by others, "a.s." stands for "almost surely". The wikipedia article quoted by @Matt is a good start for *almost surely* and its synonyms.

There is however a subtle distinction between *almost surely* (or *with probability 1*) to *always* [resp., between *with probability zero* to *never*].

Imagine an infinite series of [i.i.d. random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) which are **head** a.s. (=with probability 1), **tail** with probability zero. It is possible in such an infinite series to have a finite number of **tails** although the probability for **tail** is 0, as the empirical distribution of the series remains 1-0 (only a finite number of instances out of infinitely many). On the other hand, when one says that the series is *always* **head** one means that not even a single **tail** occurs in the series.